# Writing Unit Test Case in Angular JS using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am building an application using Angular JS. As I am new to it I don't know much about writing test cases in it.

Suppose I have a service:

```
angular.module('MyApp').

factory('MainPage', function($resource,BASE_URL){

return $resource("my api call", {}, {query: {method:'GET'}, isArray:true});

}).
```

**My Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp')

app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,MainPage,$rootScope){
$scope.mainpage = MainPage.query();
    });
```

How I write test case for this controller in Angular JS using Jasmine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would write something along these lines:

```js
describe('MyApp controllers', function() {

  describe('MainCtrl', function(){

    it('should populate the query', function() {
      var scope = {},
          ctrl = new MainCtrl(scope);

      expect(scope.mainpage).toEqual(someMainPageMock);
    });
  });
});
```

This is well documented, see the [AngularJS tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) for a quick reference, it's also suggested to read the [Jasmine docs](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) (!).

You'd also want to spy on the `query()` method, [see here](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-Spies) on how.